# How to enable directory listing in Spring Boot with Thymeleaf or JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, spring-boot, thymeleaf, embedded-tomcat-8

I created the following main class in my Spring Boot application:

```
import org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        final DefaultServlet servlet = new DefaultServlet();
        final ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/test/*");
        bean.addInitParameter("listings", "true");
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This is intended to enable directory listing under `http://localhost:8080/test/`.

If I access to `http://localhost:8080/test/`, the application shows all files in the `test` directory. This is my expected result. However, JSP files in the directory do not work (the same is true of Thymeleaf HTML files in the directory).
How do I enable directory listing in Spring Boot with Thymeleaf or JSP?

FYI, If I remove the `servletRegistrationBean()` method, the JSP files and Thymeleaf HTML files work as expected (although directory listing does not work...).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path for Thymeleaf template-processing in the `application.properties` file by adding this line:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/test/
```

For jsp this also should work (didn't tested it):

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/test/
```

Comment: Did you remove `servletRegistrationBean()` for that? I don't now how it will influence the configuration. `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` works 100%. I use this for my application.

Comment: I only added the property.